# How can I resize the font of the title attribute in a A-Frame <a-link>

Tags: aframe

I created an  element with
document.createElement('a-link')
then I set the title attribute with :
setAttribute('title','TITLE') and I can see the title but the font is too small.
Is there a way to set the font size ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reach into the `a-link` entity and [change the text size](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/text.html#sidebar):

```
linkEl.querySelector('[text]').setAttribute('scale', '2 2 2');
```

[Checkout the code on glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/mint-cumbersome-socks?path=index.html%3A18%3A00)